# searching for all referenced Object id's

Tags: python-3.x, database, mongodb, flask

so i have this mongodb data in my database. i have two separate collections. `1st: user collection, 2nd: books collections.`. `user collections` has the info about user's and `books collections` has the info about books. so these documents are connected to each other using `object id's`. so here's what am i doing: **so if  a user is donating a book. i am linking that books's `object id` to `user data`(by adding arrays of book id's ) in user data in user collection.*** so that i will know that this user has donated this particular book. so let's say if another user on the app is searching for the book and if i have that book i want to show that book's info and all the info like how's the donor and stuff like that. i think for this i have to search for all `object id's` at once and check if user query matches with the bookname. i want to show that info my frontend. How do i achieve this ?? I am using Flask and Flask Pymongo.

`user collection`

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e2aefa5ed9b24669b5461ba'), 'name': 'vatsalay khobragade', 'email': 'vatsalayvk1434@gmail.com', 'password': b'$2b$12$bPQ6/oWvMI9LppBIKl6GP.FtrkMjVj38gNW.OnLjMeXM8ei96UOOy', 'address': 'rajnandgaon', 'location': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [20.9727404, 80.69155548263583]}, 'fulladdress': 'Rajnandgaon, Chhattisgarh, India', 'isVerified': True }
```

`books collections`

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e2af0e82b9a4157f000cad8"},"bookname":"javascript book","bookdesc":"its a javascript book","donatedby":"vatsalay khobragade"}
```

`actual data (referenced data)`

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e2aefa5ed9b24669b5461ba'), 'name': 'vatsalay khobragade', 'email': 'vatsalayvk1434@gmail.com', 'password': b'$2b$12$bPQ6/oWvMI9LppBIKl6GP.FtrkMjVj38gNW.OnLjMeXM8ei96UOOy', 'address': 'rajnandgaon', 'location': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [20.9727404, 80.69155548263583]}, 'fulladdress': 'Rajnandgaon, Chhattisgarh, India', 'isVerified': True, 'donateList': [[{'bookid': ObjectId('5e2af008b814ff2f545ae3c4')}], [{'bookid': ObjectId('5e2af0e82b9a4157f000cad8')}]]}
```

Comment: You can do `$lookup` on `Books` collection with a book name & get books details with donor details as well !!

Comment: actually my application is ```location based``` so i only want to search for books which are referenced in ```actual data```. i am only intrested in the data which are available around ```5 km``` from ```user location```. which i am getting using mongodb's  ```$nearSphere``` method. i only want to search for books which are referenced in ```actual data``` becouse they are available in ```5 km``` from the ```user's location```. i hope this clarifies you.

Comment: So once you search for books for an user that are within 5kms using `$nearSphere` you can do `$lookup` for those books

Comment: so you are saying that i can do ```$lookup```  in ```actual data``` and i will get all the info about books which are referenced by ```its object id```

Comment: What do you mean by actual data? Does your actual data has books ids ?

Comment: yes ! in ```actual data``` i have something like this: ```'donateList': [[{'bookid': ObjectId('5e2af008b814ff2f545ae3c4')}], [{'bookid': ObjectId('5e2af0e82b9a4157f000cad8')}]]```

Comment: Ok you can do look up with those ids on user collection

Comment: i will try that out !